# Calculate the discriminant of $X^n+aX^{n-1}+b$, given the discriminant of $X^n+aX+b$

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, discriminant, resultant

Calculate the discriminant of $X^n+aX^{n-1}+b \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, knowing that the discriminant of $X^n+aX+b$ is $(-1)^{\frac{n^2+n-2}{2}}(n-1)^{n-1}a^n+(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}n^nb^{n-1}$. All I have seen in class is that given a monic polynomial with roots $x_1,...,x_n$ its discriminant is given by $\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$.

I tried first to search a relation between the roots of $X^n+aX^{n-1}+b$ and the roots of $X^n+aX+b$, but trying with small $n$, it seems that there is none.

Then I searched online and I found the definition using the resultant. I tried to write both determinants to see if I could transform one into the other adding rows or columns, but I haven't been able to do so.

Any help please?

Comment: @user8675309 That's not what I wrote, I said that that formula is the discriminant of $X^n+aX+b$

Comment: If the discriminant of $X^n+aX+b$ is $=K_1 a^n + K_2 b^{n-1}$ then the discriminant of $X^n+aX^{n-1}+b$ will be $=K_1 a^n b^{n-2} + K_2 b^{n-1}$. The derivation I have in mind assumes familiarity with inverting a Companion matrix, giving you a mapping (when $b\neq 0$) from $X^n+aX+b\mapsto \frac{1}{b}+\frac{a}{b}X^{n-1} + X^n \cong 1+aX^{n-1}+bX^n$. None of this uses ideas specific to resultants or symmetric functions though and you haven't stated what your background knowledge is. Given the structure of the answer, I suspect there's a nicer approach using symmetric function theory.